# button property binding "disable" not working in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, property-binding

I have created a component name servers. In servers.component.ts i have created a variable name allowServer with bool value false (to disable button in start of the app).
In constructor, I have used javascript setTimeout function to change the value of allowServer to True. The value is changing but button is not getting enabled

[servers.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvY0j.png).

[servers.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pjE.png)
What am i doing wrong??

Comment: (use the tag `angular` for Angular with versions 2 and 4)

Comment: Please paste your code here and not any image of it it's hard to debug from image for details refer https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @BlackMamba all the code are in theses two files. a simple html code  , and a ts code to change the value of allowServer

Comment: @MirzaAhsan mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ArrowFunction ()=>  to preserve this context within **`setTimeOut`**.

```
setTimeout(()=>{    
      this.allowServer = true;
 },3000);
```